# R: Replacing specific values in ONE specific row only when variable name contains a certain string

Tags: r, replace, time-series, tidyverse

I have a times series data set where I would like to replace the values of specific observations in the first row (the row where date == "2019-12-31") with the value zero. The reason for this is that the percentage returns displayed in these observations are from last year, and for my purpose I need them to equal zero.

The actual dataset that I am working with is much larger then the exapmle provided below and the order that the columns are placed in the real-life dataset change from month to month when I receive the file (except for the date column which is always the first one on the left hand side). There are around 50 observations in the first row that I need to change every month. The common trait of the columns where the changes need to be made for the first observation is that they contain the string "local_return" or "currency_return" or "twr_".

Please see a simplified example of the problem I have in the picture below, basically I need to be able to change the observations coloured red in the first row to zero. As mentioned above, the order of the columns to the right side of the date-column change every month (as well as the selection of columns). However, the columns that I need to change always contain one of a handful of strings.

I would appreciate any help! I have tried using the replace() function but I am  only able to change all variables (except the variable 'date') in the first row to zero. I can also change the value of specific observations using x[i,j] but since the columns change order every month this is not a good long-term solution.

[A screenshot of the problem in Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlpOJ.png)

Example data to copy and paste into R for easy reproducing of problem:

```
df <- data.frame (date  = c("2020-12-31", "2021-01-04", "2021-01-05", "2021-01-06", "2021-01-07", "2021-01-08", "2021-01-11"),
                  nominal_amount  = c( 5000000000, 5000000000,5000000000,5000000000,5000000000,5000000000,5000000000),
                  market_value = c(5132748596,  5463759675, 5231957361, 5212386748, 5194812564, 5192248647, 5198903366),
                  exposure = c(5132748596,  5463759675, 5231957361, 5212386748, 5194812564, 5192248647, 5198903366),
                  net_cash_flow = c(0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0),
                  local_return_ytd =c(0.12, 0.02,   0.02,   0.02,   0.02,   0.02,   0.02),
                  currency_return_ytd = c(0.11, 0.01,   0.01,   0.01,   0.01,   0.01,   0.01),
                  duration = c(4.02,    4.01,   3.99,   3.98,   3.93,   3.79,   3.94),
                  twr_ytd = c(0.13, 0.03,   0.03,   0.03,   0.03,   0.03,   0.03),
                  local_return_mtd = c(0.102,   0.002,  0.002,  0.002,  0.002,  0.002,  0.002),
                  currency_return_mtd = c(0.101,    0.001,  0.001,  0.001,  0.001,  0.001,  0.001),
                  twr_mtd = c(0.103,    0.003,  0.003,  0.003,  0.003,  0.003,  0.003))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Questions should be reproducible. Please don’t use images of code or data as they cannot be used without a lot of unnecessary effort. Check out stack overflow guidance [mre] and [ask]. Include a minimal dataset in the form of an object for example if a data frame as `df <- data.frame(…)` where … are your variables and values or use `dput(head(df))`.

Comment: I have edited the problem so that it now includes the data in a dataframe that you can just paste into R and use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a direct approach with base R:

```
#  "local_return" or "currency_return" or "twr_".
# get those column names
cols = grep("local_return|currency_return|twr_", names(df), value = TRUE)

# check cols - looks right
cols
# [1] "local_return_ytd"    "currency_return_ytd" "twr_ytd"             "local_return_mtd"   
# [5] "currency_return_mtd" "twr_mtd"  

# get row numbers to change (you can just use 1 if you know it's the first row)
rows = which(df$date == "2020-12-31")

# check rows - looks right
rows
# [1] 1

# set values in those columns and rows to 0
df[rows, cols] = 0
df
#         date nominal_amount market_value   exposure net_cash_flow local_return_ytd currency_return_ytd
# 1 2020-12-31          5e+09   5132748596 5132748596             0             0.00                0.00
# 2 2021-01-04          5e+09   5463759675 5463759675             0             0.02                0.01
# 3 2021-01-05          5e+09   5231957361 5231957361             0             0.02                0.01
# 4 2021-01-06          5e+09   5212386748 5212386748             0             0.02                0.01
# 5 2021-01-07          5e+09   5194812564 5194812564             0             0.02                0.01
# 6 2021-01-08          5e+09   5192248647 5192248647             0             0.02                0.01
# 7 2021-01-11          5e+09   5198903366 5198903366             0             0.02                0.01
#   duration twr_ytd local_return_mtd currency_return_mtd twr_mtd
# 1     4.02    0.00            0.000               0.000   0.000
# 2     4.01    0.03            0.002               0.001   0.003
# 3     3.99    0.03            0.002               0.001   0.003
# 4     3.98    0.03            0.002               0.001   0.003
# 5     3.93    0.03            0.002               0.001   0.003
# 6     3.79    0.03            0.002               0.001   0.003
# 7     3.94    0.03            0.002               0.001   0.003
```